# How to find a UICollectionViewCell's coordinates relative to the App Window

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Is it possible to translate a `UICollectionViewCell's` coordinates from being relative to the `UICollectionView` to being relative to the `superview`? So far I've been unable to translate a `UICollectionViewCell's` coordinates when touched to the `superview`. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView  
        didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = 
     [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionViewCell" 
                                               forIndexPath:indexPath];

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 
                              0.0,  
                              cell.frame.size.width, 
                              cell.frame.size.height);
    frame.origin = [cell convertPoint:cell.frame.origin 
                               toView:self.view];
}
```

I'd like to create a new frame which originates from the cell's position on the view, not in the `UICollectionView`. Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: What result does the code above give you? What are you then doing with the frame?

Comment: The resulting frame give me an origin relative to the origin of the UICollectionView. For example, if a cell has been touched after being scrolled 5000 points to the left, the frame origin after converting would be {5000, 0}.

Comment: After I've calculated the position, I'd like to pass the coordinates to a subview to display over the top of the touched cell.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This answer is very late, but hopefully it will help someone.
Dan, you have the right idea, but it is even easier that what you have. Just replace

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height);
frame.origin = [cell convertPoint:cell.frame.origin toView:self.view];
```

with

```
CGRect frame = [collectionView convertRect:cell.frame toView:self.view];
```

The problem was that you were calling the convert method on the cell, not the collectionView.

Comment: Perfection. I seriously tried 50 other things before this. Thanks. #latenightprogramming

Comment: Wow thanks! I kept trying to just call convertTo() without calling it on a certain object, not figuring out why it wouldn't work. Stupid me haha!

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly, I think the problem is that you first have to correct for the scroll view's `contentOffset`, which is easy to do since `UICollectionView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`.

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0,
                          0.0,
                          cell.frame.size.width,
                          cell.frame.size.height);
CGPoint correctedOffset = 
 CGPointMake(cell.frame.origin.x - collectionView.contentOffset.x,
             cell.frame.origin.y - collectionView.contentOffset.y);
frame.origin = [cell convertPoint:correctedOffset toView:self.view];
```

I tested this in one of my `UICollectionView` demo apps and it seems to work.  Give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case if anybody looking for this, here is how it can be done in Swift:

```
let cellFrameInSuperview = collectionView.convertRect(collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)!.frame, toView: view)
```