# How to get the relative position of a cell in CollectionView

Tags: xamarin.ios, uicollectionview

I'm wondering how can I get the relative position of a cell in a collection view in regards to the app window? I saw some examples for swift and forms, but i can't find any for Xamarin.iOS

Comment: Please show us some relevant codes. If you find a solution in swift, you can also share here and we can help you to convert it to a C# solution.

Comment: This is the code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554203/how-to-find-a-uicollectionviewcells-coordinates-relative-to-the-app-window

Comment: I added an answer with solution in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translate the solution in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554203/how-to-find-a-uicollectionviewcells-coordinates-relative-to-the-app-window):

```
public class collectionViewDelegate : UICollectionViewDelegate {

    UIView view;

    public collectionViewDelegate(UIView v)
    {
        //get the parent v when create collectionViewDelegate instance
        this.view = v;
    }

    public override void ItemSelected(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {

        UICollectionViewCell cell = (UICollectionViewCell)collectionView.DequeueReusableCell("CollectionViewCell",indexPath);

        CGRect frame = new CGRect(0,0,cell.Frame.Size.Width,cell.Frame.Size.Height);

        frame.Location = collectionView.ConvertPointToView(cell.Frame.Location, this.view);
    }
}
```